# Android Phone Setting Change Crash

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I want to change my phone to vibration mode but whenever I am clicking the vibration button the application stops working.

```
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.media.AudioManager;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuItem;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.Button;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button vibration;
AudioManager audioControl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initiatlize();
    }

private void initiatlize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button vibration = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vibration);
    vibration.setOnClickListener(this);
    AudioManager audioControl = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

}
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.vibration: audioControl.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        break;
    }
}
```

My Manifest.xml has the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>
```

Please help me in locating my error.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit** : Output in the logCat :

```
02-08 13:31:48.976: D/gralloc_goldfish(865): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-08 13:31:56.026: D/AndroidRuntime(865): Shutting down VM
02-08 13:31:56.026: W/dalvikvm(865): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.example.collegehack.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-08 13:31:56.066: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 13:31:58.656: I/Process(865): Sending signal. PID: 865 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What is the output in logcat?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I added the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to include permission in Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

and it seems that audioControl  causes nullpointer at

```
 case R.id.vibration: audioControl.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

so rewrite your `initiatlize()` method as

```
private void initiatlize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    vibration = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vibration);
    vibration.setOnClickListener(this);
    audioControl = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: @Arqam Happy to help,enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to permissions:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
```